# Swagger ui description of array parameters in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have controller that recieves object of SearchProfilesModel. It consists of array of SearchProfiles and several properties in base classes.
Method:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<UserSearchResult>))]
[Route("SearchWithParams")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
    SearchWithParams([FromUri] SearchProfilesModel model)
{
    // Some logic
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

Model class:

```
public class SearchProfilesModel : LoginRequiredModel
{
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("search_profiles")]
    public List<SearchProfileViewModel> ProfilesList { get; set; }
}
```

List item class:

```
public class SearchProfileViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("facebook_id")]
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I`m using Swagger ui (swashbuckle lib) to test my controllers, but when it generates help page for this method it shows following:
[Help page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKClc.png)

My question is - can i somehow show structure of list item (from SearchProfileViewModel) in parameters? And if i can - how? 
P.S. - Sorry for my English, it`s not my native language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Describe an array of complex objects using Swagger 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088722/describe-an-array-of-complex-objects-using-swagger-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your object is in the generated doc, take a look at mine:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {...},
"host": "swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net",
"schemes": [...],
"paths": {...},
"definitions": {
    "Data": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "integ": {
                "format": "int32",
                "type": "integer",
                "example": 123
            },
            "doub": {
                "format": "double",
                "type": "number",
                "example": 9858.216
            },
            "boolea": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "guid": {
                "format": "uuid",
                "type": "string",
                "example": "f5849915-43c8-434c-92a7-7383d1acb631"
            },
            "date": {
                "format": "date-time",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
...
```